# How to display only phone number in contact list in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, phone-number, addressbook

I opened default contact list in my iPhone app.
Now I want when I select any contact it should display only phone number of that contact and not any other info.
If that contact has no phone number then it should be display only "No Phone Number".
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select any of the contact, there is one delegate method is called,

`peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`:

You just need to set displayedProperties, where you can set the Phone number only,

May this link help you more 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 2):

The `ABPersonViewController` has a `displayedProperties` property, where you can define what to display.

```
ABPersonViewController *controller = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *properties =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], nil]
[controller setDisplayedProperties:properties];
```